# Open Graph action not working Facebook android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a story on facebook with different action such as Play, Create etc. All goes well and story also get posted but instead of posting "Played" or "Created" as action it actually write "Posted" as Action. I didn't specify any URL because in ios you don't need that URL but why it is not getting the right action in android.

I am searching for it from last 2 days and nothing helped.

My code for posting is:

```
OpenGraphObject openStoryObject = OpenGraphObject.Factory
            .createForPost("namespace:hello_game");
    openStoryObject.setImageUrls(Arrays.asList(url));
    openStoryObject.setTitle("title");
    openStoryObject.setDescription("Get this app");
    openStoryObject.setPostActionId("me/namespace:Play");

    MyOpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(MyOpenGraphAction.class);
    action.setMyObject(openStoryObject);

    Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/namespace:Play", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            response.getError();
        }
    });
    request.setGraphObject(action);
    request.executeAndWait();
```

Comment: Are you seeing different stories posted from iOS and Android versions?

Comment: no the story is same but action is different in android its "posted" but in ios its "Played"